# Imported files not recognized in OCUnit

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode, linker, ocunit

I am doing unit testing on my iPhone app using OCUnit on XCode 3.2.3, and iOS 4.0. I have successfully set up my testing environment to pass and fail basic tests appropriately, but when I import my own files (in this case, "UserAccount.h", it fails to compile and tells me:

**"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UserAccount", referenced from:**

It then says "Symbol(s) not found". This strikes me as some sort of linker error, but I have no idea what's going on. I have built and cleaned all targets numerous times, but to no avail. Here is my testing code:

```
#import "SomeTestCase.h"
#import "UserAccount.h"

@implementation SomeTestCase

 - (void)testUserAccount
 {
 // UserAccount.m //

 UserAccount *testAccount = [[UserAccount alloc] initWithUsername:@"" password:@"" deviceToken:@""];
 [testAccount registerNew];
 NSLog(@"USERID = %@", testAccount.userID);
 STAssertEquals([testAccount login], NO, @"Failure: Login should fail with blank username and password."); // should fail with no username or password

 UserAccount *testAccount2 = [[UserAccount alloc] initWithUsername:@"user" password:@"" deviceToken:@""]; 
 STAssertEquals([testAccount2 login], NO, @"Failure: Login should fail with blank password.");// should fail with no password

 UserAccount *testAccount3 = [[UserAccount alloc] initWithUsername:@"" password:@"pass" deviceToken:@""]; 
 STAssertEquals([testAccount3 login], NO, @"Failure: Login should fail with blank username.");// should fail with no password

 }

@end
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that UserAccount.m has not been added to the testing target. That will cause the "Symbols not found" error. I seen times with multiple targets in which Xcode recognizes headers even though the implementation file is not part of target.

If that doesn't work, try emptying the Xcode cache with `Xcode>Empty Caches...`.

Answer (score 3):

In XCode 4 at least you should **not** include your application .m files in your **test** target. The proper way to do this is:

1. Your Project (top left) -> Targets -> Your Test Target -> Target Dependencies -> + Your main app target
2. Switch to Build Settings Tab -> Linking -> Bundle Loader -> $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/YourAppName.app/YourAppName

A good way to see how this is properly done is to create a brand new XCode 4 project with unit tests and then see how the test target is setup. You'll notice the application .m files are not included in the test target.